# mwfeedpaser detailview

Tags: xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I just started using xcode and OBJ-c this year.
I am using mwfeedparser for a app I'm making but would like to change the look of the detailview.
right now i'm using the demo app that came with mwfeedparser to change the detail view.
i would like the detail view to have labels instead of being a tableview

i have changed this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
 {
 DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil]; 
    detail.item = (MWFeedItem *)[itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];


// Deselect
 [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

when i  run the code the detailview doesn't even come up. am I doing something wrong?

thanks  for your help. 
btw when i do get this done I'll put it up on github incase anybody else needs it

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`self.parsedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedItem:(MWFeedItem *)item{
    if (item) {        
          [self.parsedItems addObject:item];     
     }
```

}
    - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath  {

```
        DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]        initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil]; 
        detail.item = [self.parsedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

}